# Micro-sd card readable but not able to write or format

Tags: sd-card, micro-sd-card

I've a Sandisk 64gb class 10 microsd that used to work fine. All of a sudden it has become read-only. I can read all files, but I cannot delete/add any files or format the sdcard in Android, linux or windows.

Every attempt to format sdcard fails (with 10+ tools I tried) on PC (including gparted, fdsik, etc).

Micro-sd has no read-only switch. Is this hardware problem?

Comment: Are you using an SD to Micro-SD adapter?

Comment: this is my android phone's card. I've been using it on my phones, it doesnt work on any phone. For formatting on PC, I used micro-sd adapter. I checked there was no lock.

Comment: Have you tried **chkdsk** or **fsck**?

Comment: Also, what's the make / model of the card?

Comment: @sgtbeano yes, it finds no issues. Its sandisk SDXC Class 10

Comment: It sounds very much like a hardware issue if you're not getting anywhere with the multitude of tools you've tried.  I did some research on the SanDisk support site and ultimately it lead me to here -> http://kb.sandisk.com/app/ask/ | basically I think you need to log a call with them to see if they can help.